# What happens if we don't join threads?

Tags: c, operating-system

Could someone help me better understand what exactly happens when we don't join threads and why it is a problem? I understand that when we join threads it waits for the thread to complete and be terminated before calling the next thread, but I'm not fully understanding the negatives of not joining threads.

Comment: If you don't join threads, your application will be easier to design, implement, understand and shut down.  Process-lifetime threads and pools are just easier all-round.  Join() is an abomination:)

Comment: @MartinJames you could have explained why in more in-depth, so the beginners that are starting with threading and processes can have a better view